# how recursion code works for boolean function?

Tags: java, recursion

i believe this code will return at least one true and maybe it returns some more false so what the function will return at the end of the recursion for n = 15 and how it works i know how to trace a recursion method but do it use AND or OR to return the result

```
public static boolean PrimeRec(int n){
   if (n==1)
      return true;
   else
      return PrimeRec(n,n-1);
}

public static boolean PrimeRec(int n,int d){
   if(d==1)
      return true;
   else if(n%d==0)
      return false;
   else
      return PrimeRec(n,d-1);
}
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: You can take pen and paper and see which method is invoked with which parameters at each call

Comment: It doesn't use AND or OR. With n == 15 it will get down to calling PrimeRec(15, 5) which will return `false`, and that `false` will propagate all the way back up the call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see "how it works", try changing the second `PrimeRec` to this.  It does the same thing as your post but with some added output that I'm hoping will help you understand.

```
public static boolean PrimeRec(int n,int d){
    System.out.println("PrimeRec called with n=" + n + " d=" + d);
    if(d==1) {
        System.out.println("d=1, returning true");
        return true;
    }
    else if(n%d==0) {
        System.out.println("d divides n, returning false");
        return false;
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("calling PrimeRec recursively");
        boolean answer = PrimeRec(n,d-1);
        System.out.println("back from recursive PrimeRec, returning " + answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is just a very inefficient way to check if a number is prime, with the additional bug, that according to this function 1 is a prime number. its a bad example for recursion, just as you generally should not calculate the fibonacci sequence recursively.

So, for all n>=2, PrimeRec(n) will tell you if n is prime.

To fix the algorithm, change

```
if (n==1)
    return true;
```

to

```
if (n < 2)
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes any number.. chk if it is 1 return true otherwise apply recursion by decrement number by 1 ant chk if it divide by that decremented number until number decremented to 1.